# android:checkableBehaviour="all" submenu still closes after selection / how to suppress submenu close

Tags: android, android-menu

I have an actionbar menu like this

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_select_filter"
    android:title="@string/action_filter"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/action_select_filters"
            android:checkableBehavior="all"
             >
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_filter_open"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:title="@string/action_filter_open"
                />
                ...
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

I would like it to be a multiple choice filter menu dropping down from the actionbar. But when I click one of the options, the submenu immediately closes. I would like it to stay there until the user decided that all the filters he wanted to switch on, are indeed on.

I'm aware of this question but it's quite old and the solution is a hack.
[Android checkable submenu options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226710/android-checkable-submenu-options)

I also tried returning false/true from onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item).

**So how to suppress this default behaviour?**

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a menu is to let the user choose what should happen now - and then to do it.

If you have a number of checkboxes where the user can set or unset filters, then my suggestion is to follow the Android design guide:

Simply call an Activity with a small layout of checkboxes and a button to save the changes.

A less complicated user experience and a more stable App (no hacks) will be on your side.